# Make columns on the basis of one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set in R as following:-

```
a <- data.frame(name=c("AFG", "AFG", "AFG","AFG", "GER", "GER", "GER", "GER", "GFR", "GFR", 
                      "GFR", "GFR"),
            Typ = c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "One", 
                   "Two", "Three", "Four"),
            Yr1 = c(10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 88, 1, 39, 1),
            Yr2 = c(1:12), Yr3 = c(8:19))
```

I want to change this data so that the columns are based on the values in `Typ` column. That is I get the following `data.frame`.

```
b <- data.frame(name = c("AFG", "AFG", "AFG","GER", "GER", "GER","GFR", "GFR", "GFR"),
            Yr = c("Yr1", "Yr2", "Yr3", "Yr1", "Yr2", "Yr3", "Yr1", "Yr2", "Yr3"),
            One = c(10, 1, 8, 15, 5, 12, 88, 9, 16),
            Two = c(11, 2, 9, 17, 6, 13, 1, 10, 17),
            Three = c(12, 3, 10, 18, 7, 14, 39, 11, 18),
            Four = c(14, 4, 11, 19, 8, 15, 1, 12, 19))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr` :

```
library(tidyr)

a %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Yr1:Yr3, names_to = 'Yr') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Typ, values_from = value)

#  name  Yr      One   Two Three  Four
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 AFG   Yr1      10    11    12    14
#2 AFG   Yr2       1     2     3     4
#3 AFG   Yr3       8     9    10    11
#4 GER   Yr1      15    17    18    19
#5 GER   Yr2       5     6     7     8
#6 GER   Yr3      12    13    14    15
#7 GFR   Yr1      88     1    39     1
#8 GFR   Yr2       9    10    11    12
#9 GFR   Yr3      16    17    18    19
```

Using `data.table` :

```
dcast(melt(setDT(a), measure.vars = c('Yr1', 'Yr2', 'Yr3')), 
      name+variable~Typ, value.var = 'value')
```